# ListView Onclick?

Tags: android, android-listview

i have a question about adding a onClick to the a ListView, i have tried to follow the Android NotePad tutorial as much as posible but with my layout i dont quite understand how to add it in.

this is the activity class and it simpley populates the view

```
 public class RemoveForm extends ListActivity {
private DB_Conn DB_Handler;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        DB_Handler = new DB_Conn(this);
        DB_Handler.open();
        fillData();


}

protected void onListItemClick(View view) {
    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    CharSequence text = "Hello toast!";
    int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
    toast.show();

}

private void fillData() {
    // Get all of the notes from the database and create the item list
    Cursor c = DB_Handler.fetchAll();
    startManagingCursor(c);
    String[] from = new String[] { DB_Conn.KEY_MODULECODE,
        DB_Conn.KEY_DAY,
        DB_Conn.KEY_TIME,
        DB_Conn.KEY_DURATION,
        DB_Conn.KEY_TYPE,
        DB_Conn.KEY_ROOM,DB_Conn.KEY_ROWID };
int[] to = new int[] { R.id.MODULECODE,
        R.id.DAY,
        R.id.TIME,
        R.id.DURATION,
        R.id.TYPE,
        R.id.ROOM,
        R.id.ROWID};

// Now create an array adapter and set it to display using our row
    SimpleCursorAdapter entry =
    new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.list, c, from, to);
    setListAdapter(entry);
}
}
```

and this is the xml for each record.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:baselineAligned="false">
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout2" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_weight="1"
    android:baselineAligned="false">
    </LinearLayout>
    <RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1" android:layout_width="match_parent">
        <TextView android:id="@+id/ROWID" 
                android:text="TextView"
                 android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
                  android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                   android:layout_width="wrap_content"></TextView>
        <TextView android:id="@+id/MODULECODE" 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:text="TextView" 
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ROWID" 
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/ROWID"></TextView>
        <TextView android:layout_marginLeft="25dip" 
                android:id="@+id/DAY" 
                android:layout_width="50dip" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:text="TextView" 
                android:layout_below="@+id/MODULECODE" 
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/MODULECODE"></TextView>
        <TextView android:id="@+id/TIME" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="TextView" 
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/DAY" 
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/DAY" 
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/DAY"></TextView>
        <TextView android:id="@+id/DURATION" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
         android:text="TextView" 
         android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/TIME" 
         android:layout_alignTop="@+id/TIME" 
         android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/TIME"></TextView>
        <TextView android:id="@+id/ROOM" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="TextView" 
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/MODULECODE" 
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/MODULECODE"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/MODULECODE"></TextView>
        <TextView android:id="@+id/TYPE" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="TextView" 
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ROOM" 
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/ROOM" 
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/ROOM"></TextView>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

if anyone can help i'd be so grateful right now.

Answer (score 2):

You have to [override](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html#onListItemClick%28android.widget.ListView,%20android.view.View,%20int,%20long%29) the,

```
 @Override
 protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

 }
```

Comment: thank you soo much i cant beleive it! always  the simple things :)